# jQuery Validation conditional dependency: ensure text input matches value if radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a some form elements that follow a format like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="A"> <input type="text" size="3" name="weightA" id="A"><br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="B"> <input type="text" size="3" name="weightB" id="B"><br>
```

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin to conduct client-side validation. What I would like to do with these fields is to ensure that the text input corresponding to the selected radio button equals 100. I have successfully implemented this on the server-side using PHP, but would like to add a JS method to give immediate feedback before the form is submitted. I have already included a jQuery `range:` rule to constrain user inputs in the two text fields within the numeric range [1-100].

How would I go about making this work? Would `jQuery.validator.addMethod` be the way to do it?

**Edit:**  in response to Sparky's comment, I have attempted an addMethod, below:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "selectWt", function(value, element) {
        var selA = $('[name="test"]').val() === "A";
        var selB = $('[name="test"]').val() === "B";

        if (selA && ($("#A").val() !== "100")) {
            return false;
        } else if (selB && ($("#B").val() !== "100")) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }, "Selected option must equal 100."
);
```

This seems to trigger the validation for `#A` but *not* `#B`, and the error message displayed is the one specified by the `message:` rule rather than the one specified by `addMethod`. Please bear in mind I have minimal programming background.

Comment: Yes, follow the docs to write a custom method and implement it with `addMethod`.  Please update your OP with an attempt at this.

Comment: @Sparky I had a go at doing this (see edited post) but it's not quite working as I'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/maqZe/**

```
$.validator.addMethod("selectWt", function (value, element) {
    if ($(element).prev().is(':checked')) {
        return ($(element).val() === 100);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Selected option must equal 100.");
```

This rule can be applied generically.  It simply checks to see if the radio element placed previous to element is `checked`.  If so, it then returns `true` only if the text element's value is `100`.

The way it's written, it only works if your `type=text` element immediately follows the `type=radio` element.  It will need to be tweaked if you change the HTML arrangement.

---

It can also be made more flexible by passing in the `100` value as a parameter.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NFJUN/

```
$.validator.addMethod("selectWt", function (value, element, param) {
    if ($(element).prev().is(':checked')) {
        return ($(element).val() === param);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Selected option must equal {0}.");
```

...

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        myfield: {
            selectWt: 100 // use a parameter instead of "true"
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works when `return ($(element).val() === 100);` is changed to `return ($(element).val() === "100");` but it still displays the error message under `message:` (tied to numeric range validation) and not "Selected option must equal 100.". Also, the validation works for the format above, but does not work in my actual form, which is in table format. How would you recommend I deal with these issues?

Comment: @tui, I have no idea how you'd need to tweak it to work on your particular DOM structure. **Since I can only see what you've shown me**, that's how I solved it.  You would need to use various jQuery DOM traversal methods.  In my example, I used `.prev()` to target the previous element.  You'd probably have to use some combination of `('td')` and `('tr')` selectors along with `.siblings()`, `.parent()`, `.find()`, etc.

Comment: @tui, My demo seems to be working perfectly fine along with the `range` rule.  I don't see the `range` error message until I enter a number outside the range.  http://jsfiddle.net/NFJUN/1/ ~  I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish here... if the value can only be "100", then why aren't you just setting it to "100" programmatically?

Comment: The form has become quite complicated, so I only presented the elements that seemed relevant to the task rather than the whole ugly guts of the code. I have used jQuery to autopopulate the relevant text field value with 100, but it could be manually changed, so I added some further validation code on the server-side. I just wanted to use jQuery validation to trigger the error message `onfocusout` for immediate feedback. I've never heard of jQuery DOM traversal before, thanks for pointing it out, looking into it now.